# Find a data with a specific title and copy the whole column to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a VBA, to copy my data in "RAW", to paste into sheet "summary" by the specific column arrangement in my "summary" sheet.

for example, if sheet "summary" column A is COUNTER CODE, then copy the data from sheet "RAW" which the data is in B2-B5 and paste into my sheet "summary" A2-A5

I tried to use the below VBA, which it works. but in the event if the column data in "RAW" is different, i will not be getting the correct data.

```
Sub TRANSFERDATA()

Dim LASTROW As Long, EROW As Long
LASTROW = Worksheets("RAW").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LASTROW

Worksheets("RAW").Cells(i, 1).Copy

EROW = Worksheets("summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("RAW").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("summary").Cells(EROW + 1, 2)

Worksheets("RAW").Cells(i, 2).Copy

Worksheets("RAW").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("summary").Cells(EROW + 1, 1)

Worksheets("RAW").Cells(i, 3).Copy

Worksheets("RAW").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("summary").Cells(EROW + 1, 4)

Worksheets("RAW").Cells(i, 4).Copy

Worksheets("RAW").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("summary").Cells(EROW + 1, 3)
Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks!

summary

[image]

RAW

[image]

Comment: i tried to use the below VBA

Comment: Where the variable/value of this "IF" ? ---> _"if sheet "summary" column A is COUNTER CODE"_. The code you posted is just copying row 2 to row 5 of Sheet RAW to Sheet summary without condition. You can either have a value for the counter code first in sheet summary, then have a condition in the code "if sheet summary counter code value is x" .... "then copy sheet RAW where each row of the the counter code value is x".

Comment: Oops... sorry, I don't put attention on your sentence _"paste into sheet "summary" by the specific column arrangement in my "summary" sheet."_ . Please disregard my question :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the next code, please. Yo do not have to copy cell by cell. In the way the code is designed, it will also work for a header which is not identic with the one in 'RAW' worksheet, but 'RAW' header string is contained:

```
Sub TestFindCopyInPlace()
   Dim shR As Worksheet, shSum As Worksheet, colHeadR As String
   Dim colHS As Range, lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long, i As Long

   Set shR = Worksheets("RAW")
   Set shSum = Worksheets("summary")
   lastCol = shR.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   lastRow = shR.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   For i = 1 To lastCol
        colHeadR = shR.Columns(i).Cells(1, 1).value
        Set colHS = shSum.Rows(1).Find(colHeadR)' find the cell with the header of the one being copied
        If Not colHS Is Nothing Then 'Find method will find a column containing colHeadR in its header string...
             shR.Range(shR.Cells(2, i), shR.Cells(lastRow, i)).Copy Destination:=colHS.Offset(1, 0)
        Else
             MsgBox "The column header """ & colHeadR & """ could not be found." & vbCrLf & _
               "Please check the spelling or whatever you think it is necessary..."
        End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

The code should work for as many columns your 'RAW` worksheet contains...

Comment: @Yvian: Glad I could help! But, when the code answers your question, we here have the habit to tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Answer (score 0):

To make the process fully automatic, please use the following code:

```
Sub TRANSFERDATA()
    Const rawSheet As String = "RAW"
    Const summarySheet As String = "summary"

    '===================================================================================
    '   Find the last column in both sheets
    '===================================================================================
    Dim rawLastCol As Integer
    Dim summaryLastCol As Integer
    rawLastCol = Worksheets(rawSheet).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    summaryLastCol = Worksheets(summarySheet).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    '===================================================================================
    '   Iterate over all columns in the RAW sheet and transfer data to the summary sheet
    '===================================================================================
    Dim col As Integer
    For col = 1 To rawLastCol

        'Read column header
        Dim header As String
        header = Worksheets(rawSheet).Cells(1, col).Value

        'Find this header in the summary sheet
        Dim col2 As Integer
        For col2 = 1 To summaryLastCol

            If Worksheets(summarySheet).Cells(1, col2).Value = header Then

                'Transfer all values from RAW to the summary sheet
                Dim lastRow As Integer
                lastRow = Worksheets(rawSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row
                If lastRow > 1 Then 'to handle the case where a column contains no data

                    'First clear previous data
                    Range(Worksheets(summarySheet).Cells(2, col2), Worksheets(summarySheet).Cells(lastRow, col2)).ClearContents

                    'Now, transform data
                    Dim row As Integer
                    For row = 2 To lastRow

                        Worksheets(summarySheet).Cells(row, col2).Value = Worksheets(rawSheet).Cells(row, col).Value
                    Next row
                End If

                'Break
                Exit For
            End If
        Next col2
    Next col

End Sub
```

This will work event if the number of columns or rows change in your sheets

Comment: tried to run the it. but there's an error code: run-time error '1004':

Comment: Could you please tell me the line number that caused that error?